# Can't access cubit in a modal with flutter_bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have the following stateless widget. I'm trying to access the `SettingsCubit` in the `SettingsOverlay` class using `BlocProvider.of<SettingsCubit>(context).updateSettings(newSettings);` but it throws a ProviderNotFoundException.
Also tried using a MaterialPageRoute instead of a modal, but it had the same problem.

The `MovieBloc` works correctly inside the `MovieList` widget with a `BlocBuilder`, and refreshes as it should.

Am I right, that it has something to do with that the `MovieList` is in the same widget tree as the BlocProvider, and the modal/new page is a different (sub)tree? If so, shouldn't the `BlocProvider.value` pass the data over to the `SettingsOverlay`?

Here is the widget's full code:

```dart
class MovieScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MovieScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<SettingsCubit>(
          create: (_) => SettingsCubit(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<MovieBloc>(
          create: (_) =>
              MovieBloc(httpClient: http.Client())..add(MovieFetched()),
        )
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Movies'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () => {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                  useSafeArea: true,
                  context: context,
                  builder: (_) {
                    return BlocProvider.value(
                      value: context.read<SettingsCubit>(),
                      child: const SettingsOverlay(),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: const MovieList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class SettingsOverlay extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsOverlay({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Settings")),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print("save");

              BlocProvider.of<SettingsCubit>(context)
                  .updateSettings(Settings());
            },
            child: const Text("Save"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is reading `SettingsCubit` on the same context where you've just created. `context.read` will look up the widget tree (not current one).

You can add another builder for separate context.

```dart
 Builder(builder: (context) {
              return IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                    useSafeArea: true,
                    context: context,
                    builder: (_) {
                      return BlocProvider.value(
                        value: context.read<SettingsCubit>(),
                        child: const SettingsOverlay(),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              );
            }),
```